# erro SIGSEGV no uso de um ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, alocação, posix

Estou com o seguinte problema:
Estou criando um ponteiro e alocando memória nele, passando sua referência para função, mas quando vou lê-lo na função acontece o erro relatado no título.

Função:

```
void FileLer(char *texto, char *file)
{
    //
    //  Retorno
    //
    int ret = 99;

    //
    //  Handle
    //
    UINT FileHandleLer = 0;

    //
    //  Tamanho do Buffer
    //
    UINT BufferLenLer = 0;

    //
    //  Pega o tamanho do arquivo
    //
    GEDI_FS_FileSizeGet(file, 1, &BufferLenLer);

    if(BufferLenLer > 0)
    {

        GEDI_LCD_DrawString(5,  FONT_HEIGHT*5, FONT_WIDTH*0.7, FONT_HEIGHT*0.7, "File Ok! %d", BufferLenLer);

        GEDI_CLOCK_Delay(1000);

    }
    else
    {

        GEDI_LCD_DrawString(5, FONT_HEIGHT*5, FONT_WIDTH*0.7, FONT_HEIGHT*0.7, "Erro! ");

        GEDI_CLOCK_Delay(1000);

        //
        //  Para a funcao
        //
        return;

    }

    //
    //  Abre um arquivo
    //
    ret = GEDI_FS_FileOpen(file, 3, GEDI_FS_STORAGE_PUBLIC, &FileHandleLer);

    ret = GEDI_FS_FileRead(FileHandleLer, &texto, &BufferLenLer);

    int b = strlen(texto);     <<<<<< -- Linha com o erro 

    //
    //  Fecha o socket
    //
    ret = GEDI_FS_FileClose(FileHandleLer);

    //
    //  Zera Variaveis
    //
    ret                 =   0;
    FileHandleLer       =   0;
    BufferLenLer        =   0;
}
```

Chamada:

```
char *buffer            =   (char *)malloc(1024*(sizeof(char)));

//
//  Le o arquivo IP
//
FileLer(buffer, "configIP.txt");
```

Comment: Jovem da uma organizada nesse código ai, pra facilitar a leitura dele.

Comment: No `GEDI_LCD_DrawString(5, FONT_HEIGHT*5, FONT_WIDTH*0.7, FONT_HEIGHT*0.7, "Erro! %d");` - Esse `%d` não vai dar certo pois falta um parâmetro.

Comment: Qual é a finalidade do `int b = strlen(texto);` se a variável `b` não será usada para nada depois e o `strlen` não deveria produzir efeitos colaterais?

Comment: Qual a documentação de `GEDI_FS_FileRead()`?

Comment: Victor Stafusa, já reparei isso, mas ele não esta caindo no else, este não é o problema, mas obrigado

Comment: o estranho que quando faço a mesma função utilizando apenas variáveis locais ela funciona, mas quando tento a mesma passando por parâmetro acontece isso

Comment: Victor Stafusa, só para identificar o problema.

Comment: `&texto` e `texto` são coisas diferentes. O primeiro tem tipo `char **`, o segundo tem tipo `char *`. O primeiro aponta para uma variável local à função `FileLer()`, o segundo aponta para uma string externa.

Comment: Procurei no google por `GEDI_FS_FileSizeGet`, `GEDI_FS_FileOpen`, `GEDI_FS_FileRead`, `GEDI_FS_FileClose`, `GEDI_LCD_DrawString`, `GEDI_CLOCK_Delay` e `GEDI_FS_STORAGE_PUBLIC` - Muitas destas o google nunca ouviu falar. As que ele conhece apontam para uma pergunta que você fez aqui em julho e para sites que copiaram o conteúdo desta sua outra pergunta para republicar. Assim sendo, pergunto: **De onde vem estas funções? Quem foi que as fez? Onde estão publicadas?** Todos os lugares que elas aparecem na internet que eu achei apontam para você, então nos diga quem além de você mesmo as conhece.

Comment: Ah sim, e procurando por `GEDI FS` no google, não veio nenhum resultado relevante. Que bicho é esse?

Comment: pmg, exatamente isso, troquei o &texto por texto e funcionou, obrigado. Quando se trabalha com ponteiros recebidos por parâmetros e um pouco diferente

Comment: Victor Stafusa, Faz parte de uma API de um equipamento que eu uso, só esta presente no manual, eu acho, desculpe

Comment: @LucasFernandes Só por curiosidade, que equipamento é esse? Fico intrigado por existir uma API de algum equipamento que seja tão obscura assim.

Comment: @Victor Stafusa, é uma maquina de POS, sabe? Aquelas de leitura de cartões

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void FileLer(char *texto, char *file)
{
    // ...
    ret = GEDI_FS_FileRead(FileHandleLer, &texto, &BufferLenLer);
    //                                    ^^^^^^
    // ...
}
```

`&texto` e `texto` são coisas diferentes. O primeiro tem tipo `char **`, o segundo tem tipo `char *`. O primeiro aponta para uma variável local à função `FileLer()`, o segundo aponta para uma string externa.